# r ggplot2 legend: how to display linetype below symbol?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, legend

I am plotting a figure that uses both symbols and linetype to differentiate between groups (points and 95% confidence ellipses, respectively).

Here is an example plot with a similar legend:

```
  bplot<-ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,group=Species,shape=Species,lty=Species))+
    geom_point(size=3)+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F,color="black")+
    theme_minimal()+theme(legend.key.size=unit(1.2,"cm"))
  bplot
```

The problem with this is that the linetypes are hard to see in the legend because they are overlapping the symbols. Is there a way to display the linetype in the same legend as the symbols (with a single label), but below the symbols or in a way that both are readable?

Comment: try `legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm")`

Comment: legend.key.width controls the width of the legend background and was not helpful in this case.

Comment: legend.key.width controls the width of the legend key background. By making the keys wider, you get to see more of the line, and hence the line types are readable. Is this not what you wanted? If you want to separate the shape from the line type but with a single label, I think you will need to delve into the structure of the plot grob. I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: Yes, I am looking to separate the shape from the line type with a single label

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the legend is readable if the keys are widened a little.

```
library(ggplot2)

bplot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = Species,
                          shape = Species,lty = Species)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, color = "black") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm"))

bplot
```

[image]

But if you want to separate the point from the line within each key, then I think you will need to delve into the ggplot grob.

```
library(grid)

bplot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = Species,
                          shape = Species,lty = Species)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, color = "black") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm"),
        legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "grey50", size = .5))

# Get the plot grob
g = ggplotGrob(bplot)

# Get the legend
leg = g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name == "guide-box")]]

# Get the relevant keys
pos = grep("key-.-1-1", leg$grobs[[1]]$layout$name)
# pos gets the point; pos+1 gets the line

# Separate the line from the point within each key
for(i in pos) {
   leg$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[i]]$y = unit(0.6, "npc")

   leg$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[i+1]]$children[[1]]$y0 = unit(0.3, "npc")
   leg$grobs[[1]]$grobs[[i+1]]$children[[1]]$y1 = unit(0.3, "npc")
}

# Put the legend back into the plot
g$grobs[[which(g$layout$name == "guide-box")]] = leg

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Or, if you want separate legends, see @Divi's answer

Comment: For an updated solution, have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75313006/12647315

Answer (score 1):

You need the `guides` functionality. Please go through the documentation for more customization.

```
bplot<-ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,group=Species,shape=Species,lty=Species))+
  geom_point(size=3)+geom_smooth(method="lm",se=F,color="black")+
  theme_minimal()+theme(legend.key.size=unit(1.2,"cm")) + 
  guides(
    shape = guide_legend(order = 1),
    size = guide_legend(order = 2)
  )
bplot
```

[image]

Comment: I was looking to keep them in the same legend still

Answer (score 1):

One option for editing specific grobs within a ggplot grob is given in one of the  posts here. It involves following a pathway through long lists within lists to get to the relevant grob. Sometimes, it is easier (although maybe only marginally so) to edit the relevant grobs using `grid` editing functions.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

# The plot
bplot <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, group = Species,
                          shape = Species,lty = Species)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = F, color = "black") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(1.5, "cm"),
        legend.key.height = unit(1, "cm"),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "grey50", size = .5))

# Get the plot grob
g = ggplotGrob(bplot)

# Get a list of the grobs 
grid.ls(grid.force(g))
```

Look through the list of grobs. The grobs we want to edit are towards the bottom of the list - with names that begin with "key". There are three groups of three - three groups because there are three keys in the legend. Within each group, there are three grobs:

> key-3-1-bg.4-2-4-2
>   key-3-1-1.4-2-4-2
>   key-3-1-2.4-2-4-2
>       GRID.segments.819

The first is the background - of no interest here.
The second refers to the point - we want to edit its vertical position.
The third refers to a grob that contains a child - GRID.segments - the line segments. We want to edit the line segment's vertical position.

In the `editGrob()` command, `gPath` lists the grob to be edited, but `grep=TRUE` means that regular expressions can be use, and `global=TRUE` means all matches will be affected. So, only one command for each edit.

```
# Edit the 'key' grobs
# Move the point up a little
g = editGrob(grid.force(g), gPath("key-[1-9]-1-1"), grep = TRUE, global = TRUE,  
         y = unit(0.6, "npc"))

# Move the line segment down a little
g = editGrob(grid.force(g), gPath("GRID.segments"), grep = TRUE, global = TRUE,  
         y0 = unit(0.3, "npc"), y1 = unit(0.3, "npc"))

# Draw it
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]