# Separate symbol and line keys in ggplot2 joined legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot similar to the following which has both linetype and shape mappings to the same variable. I would like to keep the joined legend but would like the point in the legend to be above the line so I can better see the linetype. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, mpg, 
                   shape = factor(cyl), 
                   linetype = factor(cyl),
                   color = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(size = 2) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line", size = 1)+
  theme(legend.key.width  = grid::unit(0.5, "inch"))
```

[image]

Comment: Good question. I can't find any regular mechanism (namely within `override.aes`) that allows one to alter the _actual positions_ of legend components. I wonder if the grob can be inspected and modified, though I'm generally not a fan of doing this ... but looking at the return from `ggplot2::ggplot_build(gg)` on this, I can't find anything in any of its "simple" components (data, layout, plot) that suggest access to legend coordinates.

Comment: The legend keys are drawn by [`draw_key_*`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/draw_key.html), however I also don't really see a way how you could use them to change the position. Maybe you could write your own `draw_key_point` function and mess with `pointsGrob`, but I have no idea how/if this would work

Comment: Good find, @starja. Looking at `draw_key_point`, it hard-codes `0.5, 0.5`, suggesting there is no way to modify it in the normal language of ggplot2.

Comment: Looking at the examples, I guess it should be something like `geom_point(size = 2, key_glyph = my_own_draw_key_point)`

Comment: Not explicitly trying to close, but this does have an identical question and response (although @r2evans response is much cleaner): [r ggplot2 legend: how to display linetype below symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264596/r-ggplot2-legend-how-to-display-linetype-below-symbol)

Comment: @starja, I started writing the answer and then saw your comment, attributing you now in the answer ... if you would prefer, feel free to post your own answer (with similar/same content) and I'll delete mine. It was your find!

Comment: @caldwellst I think that is one way to go, but I think that a better method was introduced into ggplot2 after that answer, namely the use of `key_glyph`. Specifically, any solution that has to modify the underlying grob, while it may work, is inelegant and has been proven to be fragile to changes in ggplot2's inner workings. There have been other answers for ggplot2 questions that relied on changing the grob components that no longer work ... so I think sticking with the ggplot2-native methods should be preferred (and therefore not a dupe). Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans no worries, go ahead with your answer, you figured out how to deal with the grob

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @starja's cue,

```r
draw_key_point2 <- function (data, params, size) {
  `%||%` <- ggplot2:::`%||%`
  if (is.null(data$shape)) {
    data$shape <- 19
  }
  else if (is.character(data$shape)) {
    data$shape <- ggplot2:::translate_shape_string(data$shape)
  }
  stroke_size <- data$stroke %||% 0.5
  stroke_size[is.na(stroke_size)] <- 0
  grid::pointsGrob(0.5, 0.9, pch = data$shape,
                   gp = grid::gpar(col = alpha(data$colour %||% "black", data$alpha),
                                   fill = alpha(data$fill %||% "black", data$alpha),
                                   fontsize = (data$size %||% 1.5) * .pt + stroke_size * .stroke/2,
                                   lwd = stroke_size * .stroke/2))
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, mpg, 
                   shape = factor(cyl), 
                   linetype = factor(cyl),
                   color = factor(cyl))) + 
  # geom_point(size = 2) +
  geom_point(size = 2, key_glyph = draw_key_point2) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line", size = 1)+
  theme(legend.key.width  = grid::unit(0.5, "inch"))
```

[image: ggplot2 with legend points offset a little]

Note that this function needs two unexported `ggplot2` functions (`` `%||%` `` and `translate_shape_string`), which will cause this function (if added to a package) to not pass R checks. It's not hard to copy the current version of those functions into your package code, effectively freezing-in-time their bodies, recognizing that you would need to keep your package up-to-date with changes/bug-fixes in ggplot2.

This function replaces one set of hard-coded defaults (`0.5, 0.5`) with another set of hard-coded defaults (`0.5, 0.9`). Obviously there are other ways to address this, such as a function returning a function:

```r
draw_key_point3 <- function(...) {
  function(data, params, size) {
    `%||%` <- ggplot2:::`%||%`
    dots <- list(...)
    colour <- dots$colour %||% dots$color %||% data$colour %||% "black"
    shape <- dots$shape %||% data$shape %||% 19L
    alpha <- dots$alpha %||% data$alpha
    if (is.character(shape)) {
      shape <- ggplot2:::translate_shape_string(shape)
    }
    stroke_size <- dots$stroke %||% data$stroke %||% 0.5
    stroke_size[is.na(stroke_size)] <- 0
    grid::pointsGrob(dots$x %||% 0.5, dots$y %||% 0.5, pch = shape,
                     gp = grid::gpar(col = alpha(colour, alpha),
                                     fill = alpha(dots$fill %||% data$fill %||% "black", alpha),
                                     fontsize = (dots$size %||% data$size %||% 1.5) * .pt + stroke_size * .stroke/2,
                                     lwd = stroke_size * .stroke/2))
  }
}
ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, mpg, 
                   shape = factor(cyl), 
                   linetype = factor(cyl),
                   color = factor(cyl))) + 
  geom_point(size = 2, key_glyph = draw_key_point3(x=0.5, y=0.1, shape = 18)) +
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "line", size = 1)+
  theme(legend.key.width  = grid::unit(0.5, "inch"))
```

where one can set any of the key/legend glyph components (x, y, colour, shape, alpha, fill, size).